# django - urls.py how to differ almost same urls from each other

Tags: python, django

i have these urls in my urls.py:

this one:

```
url(r'^bundesland/(?P<bundesland>.+)/$','home.views.func_a'),
```

and this one:

```
url(r'^bundesland/(?P<bundesland>.+)/stadt/(?P<stadt>)/$','home.views.func_b'),
```

and i have two urls coming to urls.py:

1) `/bundesland/bavaria/` should go to `func_a`
2) `/bundesland/bavaria/stadt/munich/` should go to `func_b`

but the url 2) `/bundesland/bavaria/stadt/munich/` is still going to `func_a` and not to `func_b`. why is this?

i badly need help.

Comment: Try to change the order?

Comment: @JeremyD, i did, no effect.

Comment: Really, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/, it says that it goes in order and get the first matching the url. Is it working if you remove the first url?

Comment: @JeremyD, yeah, if i remove the first one, i am getting Page not found

Comment: Well the problem is that `/bundesland/bavaria/stadt/munich/` matches the first regex. Do you need urls with special characters to be going to `func_a`? If not, I'd change the regex from `.+` to something else.

Comment: @DanielRosenthal, yeah, i need the both urls.

Comment: @doniyor Right, but do you need special characters to be directed to the first url? should `/bundesland/b%3*#2/` direct you to `func_a`, or would you be happy with only letters/numbers in the regex?

Comment: @DanielRosenthal, yeah, i would be happy with only letters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `.+` (which takes all characters up to the end), use `\w+`:

```
url(r'^bundesland/(?P<bundesland>\w+)/$','home.views.func_a'),
```

This will take one or more letters between the slashes.

Comment: Yes, you still need the second (stadt) URL as well.

Comment: so i will do ``\w+`` for both urls? ``url(r'^bundesland/(?P<bundesland>\w+)/$','home.views.func_a'),`` and ``url(r'^bundesland/(?P<bundesland>\w+)/stadt/(?P<stadt>\w+)$','home.views.func_b'),`` ?

Comment: That's the usual pattern.  The point is that `.+` matches anything, even the `/stadt/munich/` part that comes after `bavaria`.

Comment: how can I offer only ``-`` in regex? because i have urls like ``/bundesland/bava-ria/`` and i am getting 404 for this now

Comment: Use a character class: `[\w-]+` instead of just `\w+`